# Perception of Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet by contemporaries

Tags: william-shakespeare, reception, romeo-and-juliet

It is a common trope that high schoolers, and perhaps many more people, view Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet as overdone and somewhat cheesy and shallow, for lack of better words. Would it have been viewed this way in Shakespeare's own day?

Comment: For the purpose of clarification: do you want to know how Shakespeare's contemporaries actually reacted (assuming that such information is available) or how they would have reacted (assuming that no such information is available, which makes the question rather speculative)?

Comment: This makes me think of the line "Romeo and Juliet isn't a love story to aspire to; they were teenagers, it lasted three days, and six people died!"

Comment: I didn't know that was a "common trope". I can understand that modern high schoolers might find a play about the reconciliation of two feuding families difficult to "relate" to, but I don't know what "overdone" or "cheesy and shallow" is supposed to mean here.